# How do you add a space, using an index, to a string using an integer in python?

Tags: python, string, indexing, replace

## More information

Below is my code. I am in the process of making a small program that finds Palindromes. I want the program to take user input, save it to a variable, and then check for any spaces. If it finds a space to save its index, and then to take it out to check for a Palindromes. Out of curiosity and to further my programming skills, I want to be able to add the space back later while the word is in reverse. For example, nurses run = nursesrun backward and forwards, but I also want to display it backward and add the space back.

---

```
word = input("Please enter a word")

storeVal = word.count(" ")
print()

newWord = word.replace(" ", "")
print(newWord)
print()

while True:

  if newWord == "":
    print("Sorry, but you did not enter a word")
    break

  elif newWord == newWord[::-1]:
    #use the index storeVal and add it in the string to put a space back
    print(" is a palidrone")
    break

  elif newWord != newWord[::-1]:
    print("This is not a palidron")
    break

  else:
    print("You have reached an error")
```

Also, if you have any suggestions for how I can improve my ability to ask this question or a better way I can write this question, please let me know. Thank you for reading.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Show the output you have so far, the output you're trying to get, and include the (not-yet-correct) code you wrote to solve that problem.

Comment: Why not just print the reverse of the input (i.e. `word[::-1]`) after checking if it's a palindrome?

Comment: You have an infinite loop going. `while True:` and you are not adjusting anything to justify the loop. Remove the `while` line and move the indentation back up of all lines below the line. You do not need the final `else`. Convert `elif newWord != newWord[::-1]:` to `else: print("This is not a palidron")`.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse `word` instead of reconstructing the modified `newWord`!

```
print("{} is a palidrone".format(word[::-1]))
```

Also `storeVal` in your example isn't storing the index of the space -- it's storing the number of spaces in your input string.

Comment: I have done that for this assignment, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answer, just for displaying you can print `word` instead of `newWord`. But if you want to learn how get the original positions of spaces, here are a few hints:

- [word.find(" ")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) will give you the index of the first space or -1 if none found, you can save it into a list, and than call `word.find(" ", space_index + 1)` to call the next one, where `space_index` is the index of last found space, until you get -1 which means no more spaces
- another, more educated (to my opinion), would to enumerate the string and collect all indexes for spaces in a list using list comprehension (or set, of you don't care about the order).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I knew about .set() and thought of using it but wanted something more challenging. I have done word[::-1], but my intentions where to find the space, reverse it, then add the space to show the user that it is in fact a Paldrome. Again, thank you for the hint.